# solving the equation $\displaystyle[|x^k+\sin(x)|]=p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible to show for what values of $k$ the following equation has infinite solutions?
$$\displaystyle[|x^k+\sin(x)|]=p$$
where $p$ is a prime number and $x\in\mathbb{N}.$
The symbol $[.]$ is the nearest integer(.)
Thanks.

Comment: What about $k$? Is it an integer or any real number?

Comment: $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k,x\in \Bbb N$, then $x^k+\sin x>0$ and
$$
\lfloor|x^k+\sin x|\rfloor=\begin{cases}
x^k & \text{if }\sin x>0,\\x^k-1 & \text{if }\sin x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
This can be a prime number only if:

1. $k=1$ and $x$ or $x-1$ is prime,
2. $k>1$ is prime, $x=2$ and $2^k-1$ is a Mersenne prime.